# get data from MySQL server to react native apps

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native

I am implementing a function that will show a list of user with the filter of userid in the react native app from the MySQL server database, but I faced some problem when I try to execute the app. The page is only keep loading and no data prompt on the screen:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,Component,onMount} from 'react';
import {View,Text, Button, StyleSheet,TextInput,ListView,ActivityIndicator,Platform} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from'@react-navigation/native';
import {StatusBar} from'expo-status-bar';

export default function StopJob(route){
  const[isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);
  const[userid,setuserid]=useState(route.params && route.params.userid);
  useEffect(()=>{
    let Data={
      Userid:userid,
    }
  return fetch('http://localhost/api/findid.php',{
    body:JSON.stringify(Data)
  })
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2)=> r1 !== r2});
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
           }, function() {
             // In this block you can do something with new state.
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         })
  },[]);

  const Showlist=(user,job,jobid,machinecode,startTime)=>{
 
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Third', { 
 
            Userid : user,
            Job : job,
            JobId : jobid,
            MachineCode : machinecode,
            StartTime : startTime
 
          });
 
  }
  const ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
       return (
         <View
           style={{
             height: .5,
             width: "100%",
             backgroundColor: "#000",
           }}
         />
       );
  }

  if(isLoading)return(<View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}><ActivityIndicator /> </View>);
  return(
      <View style={styles.MainContainer_For_Show_StudentList_Activity}>
   
          <ListView
   
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   
            renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}
   
            renderRow={ (rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer} 

                      onPress={this.Showlist.bind(
                        this, rowData.user,
                         rowData.job, 
                         rowData.jobid, 
                         rowData.machinecode, 
                         rowData.startTime
                         )} > 

                      {rowData.job} 
                      
                      </Text> }
   
          />
   
        </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  

  MainContainer_For_Show_StudentList_Activity :{
    
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
    
    },

  



  

  rowViewContainer: {
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  }

});
```

This is the API script that I wrote for getting the data:

```
<?php
    
    include 'config1.php';
    $CN = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    $EncodedData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $DecodedData = json_decode($EncodedData, true);

    $userid = $DecodedData['userid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scan where user =$userid";
 
$result = mysqli_query($CN,$sql);
 
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 
 
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 
 $item = $row;
 
 $json = json_encode($item);
 
 }
 
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
```

In this code the output that I expected is it shown the list of the specific id of the user which mean if userid is '1111' then the show list will only show the record of job for userid '1111'.

Comment: Is there any error code?

Comment: hi @caslawter there is no any error code prompt